# PROBLEMA RELACION TABLAS LARAVEL

Tags: base-de-datos, laravel-5, tablas, relaciones

necesito su ayuda, estoy realizando una relación de tablas en laravel con las migración, las cuales las tablas son 'Productos', 'insumos' y 'DetalleProducto', la relacion o base de datos seria de 1 a muchos (1 producto tiene N insumos) pero me aparece este error:

> 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Les envió el código de las migraciones

Producto Migración

```js
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->String('nombreP')->unique();
            $table->String('categoriaP');
            $table->integer('valorP');
            $table->String('UmedidaP');
            $table->timestamps();
            
        });
    }
```

insumos migración

```js
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('insumos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->String('nombreI')->unique();
            $table->String('categoriaI');
            $table->integer('valorI');
            $table->String('UmedidaI');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Detalleproducto migracion

```js
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('detalleproductos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->Integer('id_producto');
            $table->Integer('id_insumo');
            $table->timestamps();

            //relacion
            $table->foreign('id_producto')->references('id')->on('productos');
            $table->foreign('id_insumo')->references('id')->on('insumos');
            $table->primary(['id_insumo', 'id_producto']);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Te hago las siguientes observaciones:**

> 1. Los métodos se deben escribir en minúsculas, es decir no es lo mismo poner `String()` que `string()` entonces siempre estos en
>      minúscula
> 2. Yo he generado las llaves foráneas a través de las migraciones, sin necesidad de esta línea asi que prueba quitándola 
>      `$table->primary(['id_insumo', 'id_producto']);`
> 3. Los archivos que contienen cada una de estas migraciones, deben ser 3 en total y deben estar en el siguiente orden, verifica que así
>      sea
> 4. Las columnas que vas a usar como llaves foráneas, deben tener la siguiente estructura `$table->integer('columnaNombre')->unisgned()`

LISTADO

1. productos
2. insumos
3. detallesproductos

Si por alguna razón ya se crearon algunas de las tablas, ejecuta el comando siguiente para que ejecute todas las migraciones de nuevo

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

**CÓDIGO**

### PRIMERA MIGRACIÓN

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombreP')->unique();
            $table->string('categoriaP');
            $table->integer('valorP');
            $table->string('UmedidaP');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }
```

### SEGUNDA MIGRACIÓN

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('insumos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombreI')->unique();
            $table->string('categoriaI');
            $table->integer('valorI');
            $table->string('UmedidaI');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

### TERCERA MIGRACIÓN

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('detalleproductos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('id_producto')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('id_insumo')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            //relacion
            $table->foreign('id_producto')->references('id')->on('productos');
            $table->foreign('id_insumo')->references('id')->on('insumos');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ha funcionado el error que tenia era que en la tabla detalleproducto no le puse " ->unsigned() " al realizar eso me funciono las otras observaciones que me mencionaste igual las realice antes que me respondieras jaja, pero solo me faltaba lo de unsigned, GRACIAS!